# Problem in deciding the order of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From this : [Doubt related to formation of diff. eq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125899/doubt-related-to-formation-of-differential-equation).

Ques:

Let the solution of a differential equation is given as: $y=C_1\sin^2x+C_2\cos 2x+C_3$.  Find the order of Differential Equation ??.

This solution satisfies two different ordered differential equation as,

I) $y'''+4y'=0$   (Order 3)

II) $2\cot2xy'+y''=0$  (Order 2)

Out of two answers: Order 2 and Order 3, which solution is correct ?? or both are correct

Please clarify?

Comment: The order of a differential equation is the highest derivative involved in the equation with a non-zero coefficient next to it. For example: $y' = \tan{x}$ is of order 1, $y'' + 2\cot{2xy'} = 0$ is of order 2, $y'''+4y'=0$ is of order 3, and $0 \cdot y^{(4)} + 5y''' - 700x^2y'' = 0$ is of order 3, because the coefficient next to $y^{(4)}$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick: the three terms are not linearly independent, only two are, so that the minimum order must be $2$.

Notice that your I) is of order $3$, while your II) is not of order $3$. [Silenty fixed by the OP since.]

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I am sorry but I didn't get the final answer,: what is the order of Diff. Equ. ?? Could you clarify it more.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get the "silently fixed by the OP.."

Comment: @SachinKumar: are you unaware that you fixed ???

Comment: Oh, I have modified the Ques. Now you please see.

Comment: @SachinKumar: my answer remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You have that
$$y=C_1\sin^2x+C_2\cos (2x)+C_3$$
$$y=C_1((1-\cos^2(x))+C_2\cos(2x)+C_3$$
$$y=C_1((1-\frac 12(\cos(2x)+1))+C_2\cos (2x)+C_3$$
$$y=C_5\cos(2x)+C_4$$
It's  of order 2 . As Yves Daoust pointed out, equation I) is of order three...